# Query and access Opportunity Information from Quote Line

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I'm trying to access the opportunity information of a Quote , starting from the QuoteLine, however when I do this and do a Debug Log, I don't get the info and no errors are presented.

I tested this query in the query editor, and I do get info, although is shown as [object Object]

```
SELECT Id, SBQQ__Quantity__c, 
       SBQQ__Quote__r.Name, 
       SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Name, 
       SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Active_v2__c 
FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
```

However, when I test it in my apex trigger, I only get:

```
(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c:{Id=a4x5A000000Qnv6QAC, SBQQ__Quantity__c=3.00,  SBQQ__Quote__c=a515A000000kv2YQAQ})
```

Even if I do a for loop and access each object individually, I'm not able to access the info.

Ultimately , I want to access a field called *Active* at the Opportunity Level.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the relationship defined between the objects in your query (may be provide a screenshot from schema builder)?

Comment: It goes from QuoteLine > Quote > Opportunity
QuoteLine and Quote are from CPQ

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you were using CPQ. I don't see any issue with the query. Have you tried querying `SBQQ__Quote__c` object and whether that fetches the required parent opportunity record correctly?

Comment: debug output won't show related objects; you have to enumerate those object/fields explicitly to see in debug